# Does anyone know why base appears instead of virtualvenv? Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Does anyone know why base appears instead of virtualvenv?
How can I reactivate it? I am with Pycharm on Windows

I was working well with venv and suddenly at night he changed it for base

[image: Here it says base instead of venv]

Errors

[image: errors]

Comment: I think your virtual environment name is base.....

Comment: I don't think because when trying to run python manage.py runserver I get too many errors and seeing the messages they appear especially from the \ lib \ folder with all its content

Comment: First create a new envn https://medium.com/linkit-intecs/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-in-pycharm-a5720cc996b8 than install django than try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are not in the virtual environment.

Run the following command:

macOS: `source env/bin/activate`

Windows: `env\Scripts\activate`

*`env/` should be your virtual environment name.